# How to relocate summaryband in jasperstudio

Tags: jasper-reports, scriptlet

I am appending the contentn of my table of content like here: [Append an In-Report ToC](http://rolandtapken.de/blog/2013-04/jasperreports-append-report-toc-without-scriplets) 
Now I have my TOC at the summary band. How can I move it to the second page? Is there any better way to create table of content in jasperstudio?
As recommended in coments i used jasper book. The problem is in the table of content i get dots instead of real text which should be there.

but as you can seen in the picture by hovering the mouse on the dots the real text is shown although without page number! [image: table of contents]

Here is the XML generated with jasperstudio:

```
<textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="id" hyperlinkType="Reference" bookmarkLevel="2">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-4" y="37" width="534" height="20" printWhenGroupChanges="id" uuid="f6d9376f-7106-4292-b491-7229b297ce04"/>
            <textElement markup="html"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}.toString()}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}.toString()]]></anchorNameExpression>
            <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}.toString()]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
            <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}.toString()]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: From version 6 on there is a new template available called WaveBook. This includes a ToC report which you can put where you need it.

Comment: any idea why the TOC text is shown as dots? But when I go over it with mouse i see the real text!

Comment: Please update your question with a picture of this behaviour.

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/configuring-table-contents) for the ToC, especially the hyperlinks, through?

Comment: yes, i do not know where the problem is. I guess maybe my data set causes this problem

Comment: Please update your question with code of the textfields, in which you set the anchors.

Comment: I have added the part in: Here is the XML generated with jasperstudio. Is that what you need?

Comment: Maybe remove `<hyperlinkRef...` and `<hyperlinkTooltip...`. Also, in `textFieldExpression` there is an additional `}` which is not needed. If still no success, replace `.toString()` with e.g. `new NumberFormat` function.